# PHP & XPath Query

Tags: php, xpath

I have an XML file similar to the text below:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<Calendar xmlns="urn:AvmInterchangeSchema-Calendario-1.0">
  <Date>
    <Day>12/04/2017</Day>
    <TypesDay>
      <Type>Test 1</Type>
      <Type>Test 2</Type>
      <Type>Test 3</Type>
    </TypesDay>
  </Date>
</Calendar>
```

And I am using this Xpath to select the nodes:

```php
$xml = simplexml_load_file("file.xml");
$response = $xml->xpath('//*[text()="'.date("d/m/Y").'"]');
```

How can I take the "TypesDay" entries if that condition is met?

I hope not to create duplicates ... I'm going crazy for hours and it will definitely be a trivial thing.

Comment: https://eval.in/775280

Comment: Thanks @splash58, also your answer is very useful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few approaches to do this. First of all, you should register the namespace:

```
$xml->registerXPathNamespace('x', 'urn:AvmInterchangeSchema-Calendario-1.0');
```

I'm assuming that your node name with the value `12/04/2017` could change.

**First**

Find a node called `TypesDay` inside the named namespace `x` that the parent node has a child node with value `12/04/2017`

```
$response = $xml->xpath('//*[*[text()="'.date("d/m/Y").'"]]/x:TypesDay');
```

**Second**

Find a node called `TypesDay` inside the named namespace `x` that is sibling of node with value `12/04/2017`

```
$response = $xml->xpath('//*[text()="'.date("d/m/Y").'"]/following-sibling::x:TypesDay');
```

The result for both is:

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  object(SimpleXMLElement)#2 (1) {
    ["Type"]=>
    array(3) {
      [0]=>
      string(6) "Test 1"
      [1]=>
      string(6) "Test 2"
      [2]=>
      string(6) "Test 3"
    }
  }
}
```

After all, if you want only the entries, just add the next level `/x:Type`:

```
$response = $xml->xpath('//*[*[text()="'.date("d/m/Y").'"]]/x:TypesDay/x:Type');
```

Or:

```
$response = $xml->xpath('//*[text()="'.date("d/m/Y").'"]/following-sibling::x:TypesDay/x:Type');
```

Result:

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  object(SimpleXMLElement)#3 (1) {
    [0]=>
    string(6) "Test 1"
  }
  [1]=>
  object(SimpleXMLElement)#4 (1) {
    [0]=>
    string(6) "Test 2"
  }
  [2]=>
  object(SimpleXMLElement)#5 (1) {
    [0]=>
    string(6) "Test 3"
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I had not registered the namespace to which all had to see.

Thanks to your explanation, I can also check that the TypesDay actually exists within the file.

Thank you very much.